# Query Database for a specific Month of birthdays

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to do a query against the database where I have contacts that have birthdays in a date format such as (1980-03-13) (Year-Month-Date). But I would like to query my database where all birthdays within the (03) month. How is this possible?

If anyone could shed some light that would be greatly appreciated.

PS. I am using PHP to do my queries with MySQL.

**UPDATE: MySQL Table CONTACTS has a (DOB field) format = (date).**

Comment: What is datatype of your birthday filed?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from table
where Month(column) = 3
```

if its a string

```
select * from table
    where Month(cast(column as datetime)) = 3
```

Comment: Please use correct code formatting (see my edit) in the future

Comment: @Justin: This won't use an index if one exists on the `CONTACTS.dob` field/column

Answer (score 2):

You could use  SELECT MONTH('2008-02-03') to get the month number, replace the date with your column.

Comment: This won't use an index if one exists on the `CONTACTS.dob` field/column

Answer (score 2):

you can use the EXTRACT() function. In the WHERE clause:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dateColumn) = 3
```

Comment: This won't use an index if one exists on the `CONTACTS.dob` field/column

Answer (score 0):

Answer given by "Nick Rolando" worked for me.

Here is how I solved my same problem as yours:

```
SELECT date_of_birth FROM customer_id
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_of_birth) = 3;
```

Using the "WHERE" clause, the "EXTRACT" function does all the work by defining the "MONTH" attribute in the parentheses and knows how to only pull data which contains the month: 3

ALSO the date of birth column needs to have the proper date format, such as: "1999-03-29"

(BTW this worked for me on PostgreSQL 12)

Comment: This is really just the same answer as Nick Rolando's answer and would be better as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You could do all kinds of string manipulation on this data, but it will be sloooow. I suggest keeping the date in a DATE column, plus the month as a separate INT column. This will duplicate a part of the data, but will allow you to query efficiently (esp. if you index the month).  The reason: string operations are comparatively slow, and function calls can't be indexed.

Comment: @downvoter: Care to point out how this is incorrect? Conversion to string and subsequent manipulation scales horribly, the problem will be apparent at mere thousands of rows.

Comment: Wasn't the down-voter...but if I had to guess it'd be because there are functions to simply extract the month from a datetime...this renders adding in extra columns to contain data you can already retrieve easily unnecessary. It's kinda like having first name, last name, and firstLast name columns when you could get the first/Last by simply combining the other two...extra information in the DB that is not necessary.

Comment: @guildsbounty: They are not efficient at all - not indexable (hello Mr. Full Table Scan!). Normalization is a good tool, yes - but "keep everything normalized, no matter what the performance" is just blind obedience. I once had to do this exact thing, because the MONTH() in the query was slowing it down TWO orders of magnitude. I'm not happy about this denormalized solution, but until MySQL allows indexing on a specific DATE component (unlikely), this would be the fastest.

Comment: Ah, well, I haven't dealt with this on such a scale that the time factors would start to become damaging. Thank you for the extra info, I'm sure it'll come in handy for me in the future. +1 for the free tutorial

Comment: It is not slow and you will not see nearly that bad of a performance problem on a mere thousands of rows. I was going to say redundancy > slight-cost in performance? I'll take the latter. But I just ran some test queries on a table I have that has 561,158 rows, and there wasn't any performance difference in pulling a simple date column, and pulling the same column in a MONTH() function.. Although, that could be because it has less text to output (doubt it, but maybe), and its compensating perfectly, but still.

Comment: @Nicklamort: It also depends on the rate of queries, and the query types (for query caching etc). If you tried on a development server under negligible load, with only a few users accessing it, of course it would be fast.